# Multiple language integration Dialogflow

Tags: action, dialogflow-es, multiple-languages

I am working in an easy agent.

To the time it only had english but now I have tried to integrate Spanish to it.
After following all the steps it still says I have no actions added in spanish.

How can I add the action? I am not even using a webhook.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to https://dialogflow.com/docs/examples, there is excellent starter code you can import with the [Add to Dialogflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfqON.png) button. This includes the "Multi locale/language (Node.js)" sample, that seems to be what you're looking for.

The engineers at Dialogflow give better help than SO can, so reference them whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the relevant docs:

- [Build Localized Actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/)
- [Dialogflow Agents](https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/agents)

If you followed all of the instructions there, it sounds like you may need to reach out to [Dialogflow support](https://dialogflow.com/support).